# AmCharts4 XY Chart - how to display text instead of Zero value?

Tags: angular, text, amcharts4

I'm using AmCharts4 XY chart and I have a Zero values sometimes.
I want to display 'N/A' instead of that Zero value.

Example:

[image]

didn't succeed so far.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I've found the solution.
add   `labelBullet.label.truncate = false;`

and

```
labelBullet.label.adapter.add("text", function (text, target) {
      if (!target.dataItem._dataContext.value) {
        return "N/A"
      }
      return text
    })
```

good luck !